# NoSuchMethodError: The method 'add' was called on null -- Tried calling: add(Instance of 'FittedBox')

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In my Flutter App, I have a list of Data. It looks like this:

```
List<ContentData> contentList = [
    ContentData(
        'Mona Lisa',
        'images/0.jpg',
        '1504',
        'daVinci',
        'Louvre, Paris',
        'Mona Lisa ist ein weltberühmtes Ölgemälde von Leonardo da Vinci aus der Hochphase der italienischen Renaissance Anfang des 16. Jahrhunderts. Das auf Italienisch als La Gioconda (‚die Heitere‘) – davon abgeleitet ihr französischer Name La Joconde – bekannte Bild wurde vermutlich nach der Florentinerin Lisa del Giocondo benannt. Der unter anderem im deutschsprachigen Raum gebräuchliche Titel Mona Lisa beruht auf einem Rechtschreibfehler, denn Mona leitet sich von der italienischen Kurzform Monna (für Madonna ‚Frau‘) ab, und ist demnach also kein Vorname, sondern der Titel, mit dem Lisa als Ehefrau (madonna) von Francesco del Giocondo angeredet wurde.',
        'https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mona_Lisa'),]
```

On one point in my App, I have an Tinder image-swipe like widget called TCard (https://pub.dev/packages/tcard). In TCard theres a cards attribute which can hold multiple widgets. This worked fine but I don't want to hard code everytime I add something to the contentList so I just want it to hold a list. At the moment the list is implemented like following:

```
 Expanded(
              child: TCard(
                cards: AppBrain().tinderPagesList,
                controller: _controller,
                onForward: (index, info) {
                  print(index);
                  print(info.direction);
                  if (info.direction == SwipDirection.Right) {
                    print('right');
                  } else {
                    print('left');
                  }
                },
                onBack: (index) {
                  print("onBack");
                },
                onEnd: () {
                  setState(() {
                    toSwipePage();
                    print("end");
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
```

I also want the tinderPagesList to automatically create itself ocording to what is inside the contentList, so when I add a new entry, there should be a new entry in the tinderPagesList.
The way I tried to achieve this looks like the following:
I have the list:

```
 List<FittedBox> tinderPagesList;
```

And I have this function:

```
 void tinderPagesListAdder() {
    for (var i = 0; i < AppBrain().contentList.length; i++) {
      var currentImageNumber = 0;
      AppBrain().tinderPagesList.add(
            FittedBox(
              child: Container(
//                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50, right: 50),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(20)),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                      spreadRadius: 5,
                      blurRadius: 7,
                      offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    "images/$currentImageNumber.jpg",
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
    }
  }
```

The error I'm getting is in the title. I'm stuck and don't know how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't initialized the `tinderPagesList` variable.

You need to initialize it first then you can add. Do like this:

```
List<FittedBox> tinderPagesList = [];
```